# Google Accounts glitched somehow

Tags: linux-mint, google-drive, google-accounts, google-photos

I have been trying to download an archive that I had uploaded to my Google Drive from Facebook. When I try to download the folders, though, it says it's preparing a zip and then it never downloads. This happens in incognito mode, also.

I use Linux Mint (on the latest kernal). Logging in on the accounts in Mint and using Nemo doesn't work. It happens in both Firefox and Chrome. This happened during a big archive download spree and the archives from other sites worked, including another archive that came from Facebook. But I have this problem with most files I try zipping and downloading from Gdrive, and have for over a year.

I have tried:

- Installing [Drive for Linux](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive), but I had trouble installing Go, so I haven't figured out if that would fix the problem.
- [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) using [Rclone Browser](https://kapitainsky.github.io/RcloneBrowser/) but the thing about needing an API key stymied me getting it to work.
- [Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files) during a brief attempt to switch from Cinnamon to Gnome. That won't accept the credentials for the account even though I know they're correct.
- A full wipe and fresh install of Mint.
- Logging into Windows. There, Chrome actually popped up a notice that it couldn't download (which doesn't happen in Mint) with a help link. The link told me I either don't have the owner's permission, or to try incognito/turning off all extensions. I already know none of that helps.

Since it appears to be something to do with my accounts, I should mention also that in Gphotos on desktop, if I download an individual picture, it will pop up a notice that I'm now logged out. But hitting 'log in' causes it to just reload the popup. If I refresh the page, it's perfectly fine, actually. I was never logged out at all.

Also, Gphotos has suddenly turned faces off by itself. I had spent literally like 2 weeks making sure everyone was tagged correctly (I have 6 kids and they obviously all resemble each other) and I'm very upset this is gone. I posted an app review saying that had happened and the developer just replied explaining how to turn that on. According to their support forums this has happened to a lot of people recently.

I have posted about this issue on the Gdrive help community, Firefox's support forums, and the Linux Mint forums. I've received no helpful replies.

Comment: Are you able to get the documents on a real local drive and rebuild the Google Drive?

Comment: I didn't know you could rebuild a Gdrive. But my computer currently can't access USB drives (it's on its last legs, unfortunately - it will still read input from my USB mouse dongle but not drives). My HDD is pretty much full, too.

Comment: (it's on its last legs, unfortunately -    ....  Is that what caused the glitched.  Can you see the Google Drive intact from another computer?  Log into the drive.

Comment: I've recently logged into it at the library and downloaded a doc as a PDF while I was there. As far as I recall, everything was in there and intact.

Answer (score 0):

You have said that your USB Drive for the Google Drive was on its last legs and that is likely what has caused the glitch.

I suggest you try a good computer and log into the Google Drive from there.

You have reported that a good computer has worked.

> I've recently logged into it at the library and downloaded a doc as a
> PDF while I was there. As far as I recall, everything was in there and
> intact.

So your documents are fine and the solution as posted is to use a properly working computer.